# White Emissive Shader for GLB Export... Impossible?

Tags: materials

Trying to create a 100% white emissive texture for GLB export.
But whatever I try it always comes into the standard Model Viewer as gray:

[image: White Emissive Texture from Blender is Gray in GLB]

I have tried a number of different solutions and none work.
Including this one from Blender:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html

You can check out my Blender file here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JeI7ktE94iwewf7S9AZpvffjwJEv-d-y/view?usp=sharing

With all the different materials I have tried so far.
Using Blender 3.0.0 beta.

Any potential solutions hugely appreciated!
Cheers,
S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup you have produces a cube with perfectly white emission. (You can simplify your nodes though; just use a normal Principled node and set the Emission color to white, no need for a Texture, Add, or Emission node). You can check that it is totally white in donmccurdy's [Three.js viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/), or the [Babylon.js sandbox](https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/).

I looked at [<model-viewer>](https://modelviewer.dev/), what you're using. The reason it looks gray there is tone mapping, which is supposed to simulate high dynamic range or something. Specifically it's using Three's ACESFilmicToneMapping. This is actually similar to how your cube looks gray in Blender if you use the default Filmic color management.

There is an issue on that repo that is very similar to your question: [google/model-viewer #2451: Asset color de-saturated look?](https://github.com/google/model-viewer/issues/2451). Quoting from the response there (it's talking about base color, but the same applies to emission)...

> As I've discussed with the 3D Commerce Certification TSG, this desire for baseColor to match output color is fundamentally at odds with tone mapping, which we apply in order to avoid clipping artifacts and blown-out renders around bright reflections. This is a standard rendering practice since the results are so poor and unrealistic without it. However, to accomplish this, the gamut must be compressed. This is to help match the nonlinear behavior of the human eye.

So your cube is already as white as it can get if you're using stock <model-viewer>, sorry.

A solution suggested on that issue is:

> If you want base Color to be faithfully reproduced in the render (for instance with photogrammetry scans) you should export those using the unlit extension. However, we do currently have a bug where tone mapping is applied when it shouldn't be to unlit objects.

However, as of right now, (2021 Nov 23) I can confirm this bug still exists and an unlit white cube will still look gray.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply.

I thought that might be the case (that it depends on the viewer). Unfortunately I do not have any control over the viewer that is being used on the site where this GLB will be displayed.

As for the node simplification... yup, the simpler node setup was included as one of the materials I uploaded in the .blend file. I was just trying to exhaust all options with the alternative materials... even though they basically achieved the same thing.

Really appreciate your help :D